# Special case of handling alerts in eclipse/java selenium

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, alert

I want to handle alert not always display
for example:
I am  logged to the system with credentials: eee / eee_123
if there is another user already logged in before me, the alert display to tell me if i want to kick him out, but if I was the only one use these credentials I want to log in successfully without alerts.

My question: how to handle this alert i used this condition:
if (ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent() != null)
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

and its not working

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*. What happens?

Comment: I mean the conditions work only when the alert display but when there is no alert display the test case get failed and stop run the selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be with try catch

```
Boolean bflag = false;

try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
     } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        bflag = true;
    }

if (blag ==true) {//alert is not there}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()` doesn't return `null`. It returns the `alert` if found or throws `TimeoutException` if not. Try to switch to the alert inside `try catch` block

```
try 
{ 
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}   
catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) { }
```